# Looking to use intellitrace for VS 2015, Which one comes with it?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitrace

I would like to use intellitrace to debug. What version of Visual Studio 2015 comes with intellitrace?

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx

Look under "Debugging and Diagnostics"